# Two zeroes on x-axis of matplotlib/seaborn plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

There are two zeros on the x-axis.  How do I remove one?

```
import seaborn as sns 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline 
titanic = sns.load_dataset('titanic')
sns.distplot(titanic['fare'],kde=False)
```

[image: LINK OF MY RESULT]

Comment: Remove one zero from what?  You need to state your question clearly.  Tell us what you're trying to accomplish.Tell us what your input is, what your output is now, and what you want the output to be.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to remove a zero. There are two zeros, one for the x axis, one for the y axis. Both are needed to see where zero is for the respective axis.

Comment: It's just a formatting issue.

Comment: how to handle this

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can specify the tics via the labels keyword.  So if you don't want that zero then specify a list of numbers that you do want.

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html